# Get the code of the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I don't know how to get source code of a stored procedure in ORACLE. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following statement:

```
select text from user_source
where name = 'SP_NAME'
order by line;
```